# deploying a yeoman angular app to heroku

Tags: heroku, angular-fullstack

I deployed my yeoman fullstack app and I get an error:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I am trying to deploy an application on heroku for the first time.Any pointers to fix this?

I have followed regular tutorials to get this up on heroky, used `grunt build` and `grunt dist:serve` and it runs just fine locally without any errors.

My logs look like this:

```
2016-03-31T01:04:08.910519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-03-31T02:27:45.799910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-03-31T02:27:47.434640+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-03-31T02:27:49.777251+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T02:27:49.777274+00:00 app[web.1]: > angular-test@0.0.0 start /app
2016-03-31T02:27:49.777275+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/app.js
2016-03-31T02:27:49.777275+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437299+00:00 app[web.1]: fs.js:892
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437312+00:00 app[web.1]:   return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437313+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437313+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437314+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/favicon.ico'
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437314+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437315+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:892:18)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437316+00:00 app[web.1]:     at favicon (/app/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:47:15)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437316+00:00 app[web.1]:     at module.exports (/app/server/config/express.js:35:13)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437328+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/app.js:27:28)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437329+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437330+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437330+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437331+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437331+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437332+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:142:18)
2016-03-31T02:27:50.437332+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:939:3
2016-03-31T02:27:50.446714+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T02:27:50.455228+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-03-31T02:27:50.455710+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-31T02:27:50.455963+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.9.1
2016-03-31T02:27:50.456507+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
2016-03-31T02:27:50.456774+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-31T02:27:50.456952+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! angular-test@0.0.0 start: `node server/app.js`
2016-03-31T02:27:50.457115+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-31T02:27:50.457427+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-03-31T02:27:50.457580+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the angular-test@0.0.0 start script 'node server/app.js'.
2016-03-31T02:27:50.457778+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-03-31T02:27:50.457968+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-test package,
2016-03-31T02:27:50.458168+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-31T02:27:50.458354+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-31T02:27:50.458728+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-03-31T02:27:50.458538+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server/app.js
2016-03-31T02:27:50.458921+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-test
2016-03-31T02:27:50.459097+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-03-31T02:27:50.460235+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-31T02:27:50.460234+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-test
2016-03-31T02:27:50.465300+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T02:27:50.465522+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-31T02:27:50.465631+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-31T02:27:51.249320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-03-31T02:27:51.235239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-03-31T05:14:03.873070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-03-31T05:14:05.244594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-03-31T05:14:07.170039+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T05:14:07.170054+00:00 app[web.1]: > angular-test@0.0.0 start /app
2016-03-31T05:14:07.170055+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/app.js
2016-03-31T05:14:07.170056+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671688+00:00 app[web.1]: fs.js:892
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671722+00:00 app[web.1]:   return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671723+00:00 app[web.1]:                  ^
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671724+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671731+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/favicon.ico'
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671731+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Error (native)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671732+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:892:18)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671733+00:00 app[web.1]:     at favicon (/app/node_modules/serve-favicon/index.js:47:15)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671733+00:00 app[web.1]:     at module.exports (/app/server/config/express.js:35:13)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671734+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/app.js:27:28)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671734+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671735+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671735+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671736+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671736+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671737+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (node.js:142:18)
2016-03-31T05:14:07.671738+00:00 app[web.1]:     at node.js:939:3
2016-03-31T05:14:07.685504+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T05:14:07.696144+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-77-generic
2016-03-31T05:14:07.696638+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-31T05:14:07.696930+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.9.1
2016-03-31T05:14:07.697704+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
2016-03-31T05:14:07.697991+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-03-31T05:14:07.698208+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! angular-test@0.0.0 start: `node server/app.js`
2016-03-31T05:14:07.698406+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-03-31T05:14:07.698612+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-03-31T05:14:07.698816+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the angular-test@0.0.0 start script 'node server/app.js'.
2016-03-31T05:14:07.699013+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-03-31T05:14:07.699208+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-test package,
2016-03-31T05:14:07.699396+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-03-31T05:14:07.699601+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-03-31T05:14:07.699789+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server/app.js
2016-03-31T05:14:07.700018+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-03-31T05:14:07.700228+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-test
2016-03-31T05:14:07.700419+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-03-31T05:14:07.700613+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-test
2016-03-31T05:14:07.700803+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-03-31T05:14:07.706094+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-03-31T05:14:07.706368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-31T05:14:07.706545+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-31T05:14:08.424826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-03-31T05:14:08.402585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-03-31T08:32:27.825054+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mozzoweb.herokuapp.com request_id=28e3e7fd-8664-400b-8e78-8cf4809086ef fwd="120.59.15.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-31T08:32:28.447942+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mozzoweb.herokuapp.com request_id=3989001b-7a89-4aab-8461-e81d0dff0617 fwd="120.59.15.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-31T08:32:38.385147+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mozzoweb.herokuapp.com request_id=098cabd0-15ed-43f3-98b9-01c3130b1420 fwd="120.59.15.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-31T08:32:39.202068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mozzoweb.herokuapp.com request_id=003a4589-f69c-4219-86cf-5c8e85c1bfb9 fwd="120.59.15.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-31T08:35:40.667394+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mozzoweb.herokuapp.com request_id=ad81d2ef-4452-434c-b8e1-bd4935b372b5 fwd="120.59.15.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
[10860:10860:0331/140541:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(141)] Invalid entry with unique id: 252
2016-03-31T08:35:41.674390+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mozzoweb.herokuapp.com request_id=44245240-90ba-4836-bd79-ee37d69ddfad fwd="120.59.15.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```